# Masking URL parameters

Tags: php

I often want to redirect the user or email them a link but I want to mask the parameters in the URL so they can't tell what extra information is being sent.

For example, if I want to present a link to http://www.example.com/directory/ but I also want to pass extra parameters of an email address and a hash for someone:

**Email:** someone@example.com

**Hash:** 22sd359d5823ddg4653dfgfFSG2

I can send them to this link, but I don't want them to see the parameters:

http://www.example.com/directory/someone%40example.com/22sd359d5823ddg4653dfgfFSG2

So my first thought is just to `base64_encode()` it, but then you get those stupid == symbols at the end for the extra bytes. And also base64 encoding also generates quite long strings.

**Is there an easier, URL-friendly way to encode a string to hide its contents?**

**How would you normally do this? Is base64_encode() a standard practice?**

Comment: `I don't want`... May I ask - why?

Comment: What's wrong with the `==` at the end?

Comment: @Phil The == seems a bit too obvious that it has been base64 encoded.  More importantly though, when you send such a link in a plain text email, the == isn't considered part of the link (at least not in Outlook, I haven't tested in other email clients yet).  So you have a blue link with == at the end in black.

Comment: there are a couple url friendly obfuscation scripts in the comments to http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php which usually involve some form of gzcompress, base64_encode and strtr

Comment: Of course it's a real question.  Just because you don't understand it you want to close it? I want to mask the URL parameters in a link.  What's so hard to understand?

Comment: @Shrapnel: This looks like a valid question to me. I can also devise non-nefarious uses for such a system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could generate a `short id` and store what it's suppose to do in the database.  So using

```
http://www.example.com/directory/K2SP26
```

for example would store the person's email address in the database along with where they are supposed to go.  Check out http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_short_ids_with_php_like_youtube_or_tinyurl/

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you mean but this is overkill.  There could be millions of these links, and I also don't want to update the database every time I just want to redirect to a new link.

Comment: Should the users visit the page within a certain time frame? Maybe do some clean up by removing the records older than 6 months, or even set an expire date on the record. Proper indexing and clean up should make this work.  If you use a hash you'll end up having to decode it...I wonder what the difference in resources would be.

Answer (score 3):

Using something like base64_encode(), gzcompress, etc. to encode the string isn't a good way to obfuscate it since it's trivial to decode it.  And yes, another option is to store the value in the database and just pass a key as people have suggested.  But assuming you don't want to bother with that, what you really should do is to actually encrypt it using a private key, and then decrypt it on the other end with the same key.

For example:

```
function obfuscateString($s) 
{
    $secretHash = "BA2EC9E717B68176902FF355C23DB6D10D421F93EAF9EE8E74C374A7B0588461";
    return openssl_encrypt($s, 'AES-256-CBC', $secretHash, 0, '1234567890123456');
}

function unobfuscateString($s)
{
    $secretHash = "BA2EC9E717B68176902FF355C23DB6D10D421F93EAF9EE8E74C374A7B0588461";
    return openssl_decrypt($s, 'AES-256-CBC', $secretHash, 0, '1234567890123456');
}
```

(Requires PHP version >= 5.3.0.) Replace the $secretHash with your own secret hex string.

Note: The initialization vector ('1234567890123456') is just a filler string in this example, but that's ok.  You could come up with a way to use a unique initialization vector, but it isn't important for the purposes of obfuscating the URL parameters in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a silly answer but why not use the mcrypt functions to hide your parameters from at least the more casual users?

Answer (score -1):

If your redirect is triggered by PHP, I suppose storing the data in a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) would be the obvious choice.

```
<?php

function redirectTo($url, $data) {
    session_start();
    $hash = md5(uniqid("rediredt", true));
    $_SESSION[$hash] = array(
        'my' => 'data',
        'is' => 'invisible',
        'to' => 'the user',
    );

    $delim = strpos($url, '?') ? '&' : '?';
    $url .= $delim . 'redirection-key=' . $hash;
    // might want to send 301 / 302 header…
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit; // might want to avoid exit if you're running fcgid or similar
}

function isRedirected() {
    if (empty($_GET['redirection-key'])) {
        return null;
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION[$_GET['redirection-key']])) {
        return array();
    }

    $t = $_SESSION[$_GET['redirection-key']];
    unset($_SESSION[$_GET['redirection-key']]);
    return $t;
}
```

might help you grasp the idea…

Comment: nevermind… I didn't see the »mail them a link« part. If that is the basic idea, go with @Aaron's idea. It's the only solution to truly hide data from the user. If I see base64 encoded data, I decode it out of curiosity - anybody can.

Answer (score -2):

You have one of two choices:

1. The email address is hashed, and can therefore be decoded by a savy user.
   -or-
2. The email address is stored on your server (database) and the email link contains only the database primary ID.

If you want the most secure method, that also gives the prettiest URLs, use method 2. If you absolutely do not want to store the email address in your database, then either use a common hash, such as base64 or even rot13, or roll your own. You will find that rolling your own is not simply, but it will stop most casual users from trying to peek inside the hash.

Answer (score -5):

Its a bit hacky, but if you send them a page containing:

```
<form id="getme" action="directory/someone" method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="email" value="someone@example.com">
</form>
<script> document.getElementById("getme").sumbit();</script>
```

As soon as that loads (assuming they have javascript enabled), they will be redirected where you want them with no url dirtyness.

Comment: Please don't call an ugly solution "hacky". Not to mention email part of the question

Comment: Sorry, this is a really bad solution.

Comment: I thought "hacky" was the action of using a technology for something other than what it was designed for? ... I get that my answer does not address the email problem but I thought it was worth a mention. For my own learning, could you explain ugly vs hacky for me?